# Laptops integrated microphone ringing noise when camera is in-use

Tags: laptop, microphone, webcam, noise

I am using an Asus (n552vx-fy024d) laptop from 2016. The laptop has an integrated webcam and microphone. The microphone works flawlessly when the camera is not activated. But, when the camera is in use (by any software), the microphone makes a ringing noise. Also, this noise changes tunes depending on the video resolution.

[Video demonstration](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Fqg_wVb28ski2R-VDWK4oCf-TMI_X74/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Sounds like a design error cause by EMI;  Has the camera always caused this problem?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound I have never used the camera and microphone before. I don't know the answer to that. Also, what is EMI?

Comment: You should also get support from the Manufacturer. I have 3 machines here with integrated camera and microphone. There is no interference between the two devices in Zoom, Skype, Adobe meetings on all 3 computers.